# MongoDB replica set IDs do not match

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I created a replica set with Docker Swarm. Here is what I did:

1. Created three volumes (mongo-1, mongo-2, mongo-3)
2. Created three services with the following code:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mongo-1:
    image: mongo:4.4.2
    command:
     - /usr/bin/mongod
     - --bind_ip_all
     - --replSet
     - jm-replica
     - --journal
     - --dbpath
     - /data/db
     - --enableMajorityReadConcern
     - 'false'
     - --port
     - '27030'
    ports:
     - 27030:27030
    volumes:
     - mongo-1:/data/db
    networks:
     - mongo
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
  mongo-2:
    image: mongo:4.4.2
    command:
     - /usr/bin/mongod
     - --bind_ip_all
     - --replSet
     - jm-replica
     - --journal
     - --dbpath
     - /data/db
     - --enableMajorityReadConcern
     - 'false'
     - --port
     - '27031'
    ports:
     - 27031:27031
    volumes:
     - mongo-2:/data/db
    networks:
     - mongo
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
  mongo-3:
    image: mongo:4.4.2
    command:
     - /usr/bin/mongod
     - --bind_ip_all
     - --replSet
     - jm-replica
     - --journal
     - --dbpath
     - /data/db
     - --enableMajorityReadConcern
     - 'false'
     - --port
     - '27032'
    ports:
     - 27032:27032
    volumes:
     - mongo-3:/data/db
    networks:
     - mongo
    logging:
      driver: json-file
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 512M
networks:
  mongo:
    driver: overlay
volumes:
  mongo-1:
    external: true
  mongo-2:
    external: true
  mongo-3:
    external: true
```

3. I increased `mongo-3` to 2 replicas.
4. I increased `mongo-1` to 2 replicas.
5. I received an error that there is no more resource on node(s).
6. I decreased service replica to 1.

However, when I open mongo shell (with SSL) I can see:

```
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongo-1:27030",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 156,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1607632609, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-12-10T20:36:49Z"),
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 95732,
            "configTerm" : -1,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo-2:27031",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-12-10T22:43:23.968Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "replica set IDs do not match, ours: 5fd22a776b0ed74077c65ca8; remote node's: 5fd29e358b77ac2c30973a4c",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : -1,
            "configTerm" : -1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "mongo-3:27032",
            "health" : 0,
            "state" : 8,
            "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
            "uptime" : 0,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-12-10T22:43:23.744Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "replica set IDs do not match, ours: 5fd22a776b0ed74077c65ca8; remote node's: 5fd29e358b77ac2c30973a4c",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : -1,
            "configTerm" : -1
        }
    ],
```

My error is: `replica set IDs do not match, ours: 5fd22a776b0ed74077c65ca8; remote node's: 5fd29e358b77ac2c30973a4c`

This is not the first time this happens. Obviously, there is some misconfiguration on my side. Anyone had similar situation?

Thanks!

Comment: So what are you trying to do and how many replica sets are you trying to set up?

Comment: I figured out that I shouldn't increase `replicas` in Swarm. I just can add more secondary nodes but without increasing `replicas` in Swarm.